# Iterate a given dictionary while preserving its order

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a nested dictionary in which it has the ordering that I had wanted.
But as soon as I tried to iterate the items within then, trying to increment a key, the ordering of the objects are already sorted in alphabetical mode in the first `for` loop, is throwing off the increment.

```py
given = {
    "testC": { "0": { "ccc": ["c100"] } },
    "testA": { "1": { "aaa": ["a100", "a200"] } }, 
    "testB": { "2": { "bbb": [] }}
}


index_order = 0

for k1, k2 in given.items(): # the ordering is change here, where testA will reordered
    for page_index_order in given[k1].keys():
        var = given[k1][page_index_order]

        if page_index_order != index_order:
            index_order += 1
        else:
            index_order = page_index_order

        given[k1][index_order] = var
        given[k1].pop(page_index_order)

pprint(given)

'''
{'testA': {1: {'aaa': ['a100', 'a200']}},
 'testB': {3: {'bbb': []}},
 'testC': {2: {'ccc': ['c100']}}}
'''
```

I was expecting my results to be (same ordering but note the index value where I expected testC to be 1 but it return me 2 instead):

```py
{'testC': {1: {'ccc': ['c100']}},
 'testA': {2: {'aaa': ['a100', 'a200']}},
 'testB': {3: {'bbb': []}}}
```

I tried using `OrderedDict(given)` in the first `for` loop, but it returns a sorted dictionary.

Comment: Can you explain further why `OrderedDict` didn't work for you? It does retain insertion order (without performing any sorting) and for earlier python versions this is the way to go

Comment: You are looking for ```collections.OrderedDict```.

Comment: Dictionaries only maintain insertion order in Python 3.7+ Even then, it is usually better to not use them as ordered structures. In any case, you will have to use some kind of ordered data-structure to achieve what you want. How, **exactly** is OrderedDict not working for you?

Comment: I tried using `for k1, k2 in OrderedDict(given).items():` to 'store' the ordered structure

Comment: if `given` was *already* a regular dictionary then there converting to an `OrderedDict` is too late, you need to sort the keys and values into the order you want then convert to an `OrderedDict` directly

Comment: @TehKi no, again, `given` is a `dict`, the `dict` is *inherently unordered*. Wrapping it in `OrderedDict` is *simply going to maintain that arbitrary order*. You have to *start and work with only OrderedDict objects if you want to have ordered dictionaries*. Or work with Python 3.7+

Answer (score 0):

```
given = {
    "testC": { "0": { "ccc": ["c100"] } },
    "testA": { "1": { "aaa": ["a100", "a200"] } }, 
    "testB": { "2": { "bbb": [] }}
}
given_keys = ["testC", "testA", "testB"]  # decide order
sorted_given = OrderedDict([(k, given[k]) for k in given_keys])
```

Answer (score 0):

Your dict would be properly ordered if you either use Python 3.7+ or `collections.OrderedDict`, but if you use a regular dict in Python 3.7+ the problem would be that `pprint` always prints dicts with sorted keys, with no option not to. Use `print` instead to output the dict keys in their actual order:

```
given = {
    "testC": { "0": { "ccc": ["c100"] } },
    "testA": { "1": { "aaa": ["a100", "a200"] } }, 
    "testB": { "2": { "bbb": [] }}
}

index_order = 0

for k1, k2 in given.items():
    for page_index_order in list(given[k1]):
        var = given[k1][page_index_order]

        if page_index_order != index_order:
            index_order += 1
        else:
            index_order = page_index_order

        given[k1][index_order] = var
        given[k1].pop(page_index_order)

print(given)
```

This outputs (in Python 3.7):

```
{'testC': {1: {'ccc': ['c100']}}, 'testA': {2: {'aaa': ['a100', 'a200']}}, 'testB': {3: {'bbb': []}}}
```

Or with `collections.OrderedDict`:

```
given = OrderedDict((
    ("testC", { "0": { "ccc": ["c100"] }}),
    ("testA", { "1": { "aaa": ["a100", "a200"] }} ),
    ("testB", { "2": { "bbb": [] }})
))

index_order = 0

for k1, k2 in given.items(): # the ordering is change here, where testA will reordered
    for page_index_order in list(given[k1]):
        var = given[k1][page_index_order]

        if page_index_order != index_order:
            index_order += 1
        else:
            index_order = page_index_order

        given[k1][index_order] = var
        given[k1].pop(page_index_order)

print(given)
```

This outputs:

```
OrderedDict([('testC', {1: {'ccc': ['c100']}}), ('testA', {2: {'aaa': ['a100', 'a200']}}), ('testB', {3: {'bbb': []}})])
```